# Namespace not specified error while doing React Native upgrade with Gradle 8.0

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I recently started upgrading our `React Native` project from `v0.69.7` to `v0.72.5`. And as a part of this I’ve had to upgrade the `Gradle` version of my `Android` project to `8.x`. This is how the line in my `gradle.properties` looks:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.1-all.zip
```

And in the project level `build.gradle`:

```
//
dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.0")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
//
```

After this, now I’ve started getting this error in several of my dependencies:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-flipper'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
   > Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.
```

This is just one example, but it’s happening with almost all of my dependencies, basically.

Is there a script I can write in the app-level `build.gradle` file that can basically add a unique `namespace` property to all the libraries that don’t have it? Because at the moment, I’m doing it one-by-one and creating patches using `patch-package` and it’s very time-consuming. There must be a better way to do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue upgrading from Gradle 7.4 to 8+. Where you able to fix this?

Comment: same issue here. how can we fix it? manual way is also fine

Comment: same here! Hopefully someone has a fix soon!

Comment: In the meantime, how I'm fixing this: I have to manually add the namespace in the failing library at /node_modules/[library] and then invalidate cache to retry and find out the next one failing. Lucky me only have to do it three times.